# Totals by Day of week over a 2 week period for 1 year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Adding the query (so far) and the result....

```
DECLARE @var_StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @var_EndDate DATETIME

SET @var_StartDate = '11/25/2017' -- Set the start date
SET @var_EndDate = '11/23/2018';  --Set the end date

SELECT
    DATENAME(DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) AS Day,
    FORMAT(SUM(TRANSACTIONS), '#,0.') AS Transactions
FROM 
    VTOTALS
WHERE  
    APPLYDATE BETWEEN @var_StartDate AND @var_EndDate
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE)
ORDER BY 
    CASE
       WHEN DATENAME (DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) = 'Sunday'     THEN 1
       WHEN DATENAME (DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) = 'Monday'     THEN 2
       WHEN DATENAME (DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) = 'Tuesday'    THEN 3
       WHEN DATENAME (DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) = 'Wednesday'  THEN 4
       WHEN DATENAME (DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) = 'Thursday'   THEN 5
       WHEN DATENAME (DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) = 'Friday'     THEN 6
       WHEN DATENAME (DW, VTOTALS.APPLYDATE) = 'Saturday'   THEN 7
    END ASC
```

Output:

```
Day                            Transactions
Sunday                         10,697,804
Monday                         25,222,976
Tuesday                        25,001,258
Wednesday                      24,986,845
Thursday                       25,039,354
Friday                         24,591,728
Saturday                       12,087,903
```

I am looking for transaction totals by day of week over each day of a pay period for a 1 year timeframe. I can get the DOW but want to split into DOW for week 1 and week 2 over the year between 11/25/17 - 11/23/18

```
Week 1
Sun 1,980
Mon 38,987
Tue 28,132
Wed 30,879
Thu 30,769
Fri 39,902
Sat 41,912
Week 2 
Sun 2,280
Mon 37,987
Tue 29,132
Wed 36,879
Thu 39,769
Fri 42,902
Sat 44,912
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Take the number of days since some given date, and calculate X % 14.  This divides the result by 14 and returns the remainder which will be a number in the range 0 through 13.  If you want your result to start on a Sunday, then make sure the given date is a Sunday.

```
create table VTOTALS
(APPLYDATE date,
[TRANSACTIONS] money)
go
set nocount on
declare @Y int = 0
while @Y < 10000
begin
  insert into VTOTALS(ApplyDate,Transactions)
  values(
  DateAdd(day,  @Y % 1000,
     '2017-01-01T00:00:00.000' ),
  (@Y + 314159)%271828 )
  set @Y=@Y+1
end

go

DECLARE @var_StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @var_EndDate   DATETIME

SET @var_StartDate = '2017-11-25T00:00:00.000'  -- Set the start date
SET @var_EndDate   = '2018-11-23T00:00:00.000'; -- Set the end date

with VWeeks as
( select 
   DateDiff(day,
            '1899-12-31T00:00:00.000',
            ApplyDate)%14 
   as ZeroToThirteen,
   * from VTOTALS
  WHERE  
    APPLYDATE BETWEEN @var_StartDate AND @var_EndDate )

SELECT
  ZeroToThirteen / 7 + 1 as WeekNum,
  DateName ( DW, DateAdd ( day, 
         ZeroToThirteen,
          '1899-12-31T00:00:00.000'  ) ) as DayName,
  FORMAT(SUM(TRANSACTIONS), '#,0.') AS Transactions
FROM 
  VWeeks
GROUP BY
  ZeroToThirteen
ORDER BY
  ZeroToThirteen
```

returns

```
WeekNum     DayName                        Transactions
----------- ------------------------------ ----------------
1           Sunday                         12,307,100
1           Monday                         12,307,360
1           Tuesday                        12,307,620
1           Wednesday                      12,307,880
1           Thursday                       12,308,140
1           Friday                         12,308,400
1           Saturday                       12,308,660
2           Sunday                         12,308,920
2           Monday                         12,309,180
2           Tuesday                        12,309,440
2           Wednesday                      12,309,700
2           Thursday                       12,309,960
2           Friday                         12,310,220
2           Saturday                       12,306,840
```

Comment: I thought I saw where someone was asking for more details.... so here is my query (so far)

Answer (score 0):

You want weeks that start on Sunday, so you can use the `mode` argument to `week`.  If you just want the values for one year:

```
select week(dte, 0), sum(total)
from t
where dte >= '2017-01-01' and dte < '2018-01-01'  -- or however you define "year"
group by week(dte, 0);
```